# How to add more data to be stored in jenkins rest api

Tags: api, jenkins, continuous-integration

To make the question simple, I know that I can get some build information with https://jenkins_server/...///api/json|xml|python. And I get a lot of information for that build record.

However, I want to add more information to that build record. For example, the docker image created, or the tickets or files changed from last build to create release note, ... etc. How do I do that?

For now, I use a script to create a json file as an artifact and call that json file to get these information, but it seems a duplicate if I can add more data to the jenkins build object directly.

Comment: That's true. We also have a use case to populate custom information, such as approvals and overrides done by the jenkins jobs. It may be worth exploring option of extending the api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jenkins remote access API is designed to provide access to generic Jenkins-*internal* information, like build numbers, timestamps, fingerprints etc.

If you want to add your own data there, then you must extend Jenkins accordingly, e.g., by designing a plugin that advertises your (custom) information items as standard Jenkins-"internal" data. If you want to do that, you may want to have a look at they way fingerprint information is handled (I found that quite instructive).

However, I'd recommend that you stick with your current approach, and keep generic Jenkins-internal information separated from Job-specific data. It is less effort and clearly separates your own data from Jenkins' data.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid so, but it just seems to me that it would've been so convenient to have info from one place.