# How to add more/custom data to be stored in jenkins rest api

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958241/how-to-add-more-data-to-be-stored-in-jenkins-rest-api).

What I want is that when my pipelines run, I want to add some information in the job build so that when a REST API call is made it return existing info as well as info that I added to the job build-

Currently, the info present in this API has information like job names, build number, etc...

```
http://example.com/jenkins/<job_name>/<build_number>/api/json
```

I see there is a plugin that can be used to do this : [Env Injector](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/). But there is lot of effort to just add little info in existing API. It does not have good support of Jenkins pipeline and isn't that mainstream.

Other way is that I could just write a JSON file on the system where Jenkins is running and make it available over HTTP. This doesn't involve REST APIs but does what I want.

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just metadata you can use the job description and parse it with Regex using Groovy

```
def jobDescription = job.getDescription();

// regex match of #tags, capture "tag" from "#tag"
def tagMatches = (jobDescription =~ /#(\S+)/)
```

Then iterate over tagMatches

```
 tagMatches.each { match ->
 
}
```